# In android, I have Edittext view containing Spannable text

Tags: java, android, hybrid-mobile-app

In Android, I have an Edittext view containing Spannable text including images in that. when I convert it to HTML using "toHTML" I am getting image source as a null. Anybody help me how to get the name of image in place of null.

example i have content like "abhi"[Some image]

when I convert it I am getting HTML as below.

```
<p dir="ltr"><img src="null">&nbsp; <u>abhi</u></p>
```

Instead of that i want

```
<p dir="ltr"><img src="imagename">&nbsp; <u>abhi</u></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the spanned text is constructed. Suppose the image contained in the spanned text is an  ImageSpan instance.

**[ImageSpan](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/style/ImageSpan.java)** has many constructors:

- ImageSpan(Drawable d, String source)
- ImageSpan(Drawable d, String source, int verticalAlignment)
- ImageSpan(Context context, Uri uri)
- ImageSpan(Context context, Uri uri, int verticalAlignment)

Those constructors will assign a value to **mSource**(an internal member of ImageSpan), which will be later used by **Html.toHtml()** to generate a valid **src**.

Other commonly used constructor of ImageSpan:

- ImageSpan(Bitmap b)
- ImageSpan(Context context, Bitmap b)
- ImageSpan(Drawable d)

When image in spanned text is created using above constructors, you will get **null** as src.

Answer (score 0):

String htmlString = Html.toHtml(SpannableText);

Comment: i did that but i am getting null in place of img source